# How to resolve convertfrom-stringdata error with name=value

Tags: powershell

command is ((Get-WindowsFeature  | Format-List|out-string).Trim().replace(':', '=').replace('', '\') -split '(\r?\n){2,}') and
Is there a way to put all multi-lines into a single for selected Name's like only to "Description"

```
Name                      = AD-Certificate
DisplayName               = Active Directory Certificate Services
Description               = Active Directory Certificate Services (AD CS) is used to create certification authorities and related role services that allow you 
                            to issue and manage certificates used in a variety of applications.
Installed                 = False
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ((Get-WindowsFeature  | Format-List|out-string).Trim().replace(':', '=').replace('\', '\\') -split '(\r?\n){2,}') |where-object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}|convertfrom-stringdata|convertto-json
convertfrom-stringdata : Data line '                            to issue and manage certificates used in a variety of applications.' is not in **'name=value'**
format.
At line:1 char:165
+ ... ct {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}|convertfrom-stringdata|convert ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

Comment: The error message states the error clearly. Line `to issue and manage...` doesn't follow `name=value` format, as there is no part `name`, nor `=`. The `Description` is split to two lines, so consider joining those. Use interment variables instead of an oneliner.

Comment: Thanks, von, Yes need to join multi-lines, I am not able to understand How to place regex in a generic way since Get-WindowsFeature command is producing large data.

Comment: When you use `format-list|out-string` to convert existing objects into string-only representation, you lose object properties. Populate a collection with `get-windowsfeature` and loop through it with a `foreach`. Then access each iteration objects' attributes.